# Use a variable as attribute for an object, how to?

Tags: javascript, json, object

For the following tree

```
var items = {
  'drinks': [
    {
      'name': 'coke',
      'sugar': '1000'
    },
    {
      'name': 'pepsi',
      'sugar': '900'
    }
  ]
};
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
function get_values(data) {
  var items = JSON.parse(items)
  return items.data[0].name;
}
get_values('drinks');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to use the contents of a variable as the accessor for a property, you must use array syntax:

```
myObject[myKey]
```

In your case, you need something like:

```
var items = JSON.parse(items)

function get_values(data) {
    return items[data][0].name;
}

get_values('drinks');  // returns "coke"
```

Note that this is specifically only returning the name of the *first* element in the array `items.drinks`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply access the property value based on its name.

Using bracket notation:

```
items['drinks'];
```

Or, using dot notation, [which is possible in this case](http://mothereff.in/js-properties#drinks):

```
items.drinks;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access an object as an associative array too.

`console.log(items['drinks']);`

Comment: there's no such thing as a "JSON object".